# Xampp PHP7 with PHP5 in Windows

Tags: php, xampp

I have a Xampp version that it has PHP 5. It is working ok, the problem is that I installed a new Xampp which it has PHP 7, I have first xampp running in localhost:80 and the another xampp in localhost:8085.

I have the two Xampp in different folder, first one in C:/xampp and the second one in C:/xampp7

When i navigate with cmd to Xampp7 and I put on the command line php -v. I do not understand why it still shows me PHP 5 if this xampp has PHP 7. I would like to know why does this happen? and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a php installation on windows, in order to invoke PHP from cli either you have to refer the full path to the `php.exe`

```
C:\Users\YourUser> c:/xampp7/php/php.exe  -v
```

...or you have your path variables set up properly, so the PHP directory will be searched for when you call `php.exe`.

If you have two xampp folders and call `php.exe` from anywhere else besides a php folder, then windows will look for the path variable and detect the first one found.

If you want to change this behaviour, either use an absolute path like described above, or set your path variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, php5 is set in your environment variable "path". That's why cmd "php -v" reported php5.

If you set php7 path in environment variable "path", then cmd "php -v" will return php7.

So, whether or not you install xampp in different folder it does not execute according to folder rather execute php or mysql according to environment variable "path".

The best you can do to run different application for different version of php by adding different version of php in xampp. [help link](https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-upgrade-lower-version-to-latest-php-version-in-xampp-on-windows-f7be9a70bbb0).
Or you can leave xampp and start using [laragon portable](http://laragon.org)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the Command Search Sequence in Windows: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120
(Headline: Command Search Sequence)

If you are `cd'd` into a folder, the local file (Step 6) has precedence over folders listed in the `PATH` variable (Step 7)

However, you just `cd'd` into `C:\Xampp7` - which will result in a final lookup in the `PATH`, cause `C:\Xampp7` does not contain a `php.exe`

If you would `cd` into `C:\Xampp7\php\bin` and run `php -v` it will report Version 7 as expected.

Depending on what you need to achieve, use absolute paths, or change your `PATH` Variable.